# Joining a list to make a string for a dictionary key

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings.

Here I tried to divide it into two parts:

```
word_tag = line[:-1] + "/" + line[-1]
```

One is from the first to one before the last, ant the other is the last one which is the tag.

However, it gives me the following error:

The line is:

```
line: ['#', 'DELM']
```

> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

I want to store it as a key, is there any better way to store it so that I can retrieve the tag part better?:

```
 if word_tag in emissionProbDict.keys():
        emissionProbDict[word_tag] = emissionProbDict[word_tag] + line.count(word_tag)
    else:
        emissionProbDict[word_tag] = line.count(word_tag)
```

Comment: Try `word_tag = line[:-1] + ["/"] + line[-1]`

Comment: why did you put the `"/"` there? what was your goal with that? put a comma and it would make a tuple, and work just fine. `word_tag_split = line[:-1], line[-1]` Having said that, i think it would help make things clearer if you add an example of what you were trying to do. (and an example is called [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) i swear) :(

Comment: There error is very much self explanatory.

Comment: check `print( line[:-1] )` and `print( line[-1])` - as I understand first is list of strings (in your example it will be list with single string) , second is single string (not list). You can't concatenate list with string. You can `append()` string to list of strings or you have to create list with single string - `[ line[-1] ]` and `[ "/" ]`. You can even do `line[:-1] + [ "/", line[1] ] `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `print( line[:-1] )` and `print( line[-1] )`.
You have list with one element `[ "#" ]` and single string `"DELM"`, not list.
You can't concatenate list with string.

You can `append()` string to list

```
line = ['#', 'DELM']

word_tag = line[:-1]     # list
word_tag.append("/")     # append element to list
word_tag.append(line[1]) # append element to list
```

or you have to convert string to list

```
word_tag = line[:-1] + [ "/" ] + [ line[1] ]
```

or even

```
word_tag = line[:-1] + [ "/", line[1] ]
```

or using `.extend()`

```
word_tag = line[:-1]
word_tag.extend( [ "/", line[1] ] )
```

If you need it as string then you can do

```
word_tag = "".join( word_tag )
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can also convert first list `[ "#" ]` to string at start and concatenate strings

```
word_tag = "".join( line[:-1] )  + "/" + line[1]
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you want list as key in dictionary then you can't do this because key has to be immutable and list is mutable - but you can use tuple as key in dictionary because tuple is immutable.

```
word_tag = tuple( line[:-1] + [ "/" ] + [ line[1] ] )
```

Comment: But I guess as a key for dictionary I want all of them as one string? If yes, how can I change them to a string?

Comment: `"".join( word_tag )`

Comment: you can't use list as key in dictionary because list is mutable and key has to be immutable but you can use `tuple()` as a key because it is immutable

Comment: please if you find the question worth answering, vote it up because it has already a -1 vote.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want a list or a string as output?

If you want list:

```
word_tag = line[:-1] +["/"] + [line[-1]]
```

If you want string:

```
word_tag=''.join(line[:-1]) + '/' + line[-1]
```

Comment: I prefer list if I can use it as a key for a dictionary

Comment: you can't use list as key since it's unhashable. You can use tuple instead.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood, you are trying to concatenate the list elements from `first` to `last-1` and then the `/` and then the `last` element of the list.

For that you need to join the elements from **(** `first` to `last-1` **)** and then add `/` and `last` element.

Try this.

`word_tag = ''.join(line[:-1])+'/'+line[-1]`

The `''.join(line[:-1])` concatenates the list elements from `first` to `last-1`.